# Intercepting links from browser to my android app not working on lollipop

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have setup the code in my manifest to intercept the links so that those links only open in my app. Here is my code:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:path="/doSomething"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This code is working fine on pre-lollipop devices and opening proper activity but on lollipop devices, it is opening the last opened activity.

Do i need to something special for lollipop devices?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi.. I am facing the same issue.I cant open my application.It works fine on pre-lollipop devices.Help me if U find any solution.